# ASP.NET Core OData response json serialization nullvalue handling

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, odata

Consider two endpoints exposing data as OData.

The first in an `ODataController`:

```
private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

[HttpGet("api/[controller]/GetWeatherData")]
[EnableQuery]
public IActionResult GetWeatherData()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .AsQueryable();

    return Ok(query);
}
```

The second in a separate `ODataController`:

```
[EnableQuery]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .AsQueryable();

    return Ok(query);
}
```

Both have the same code and both have the `EnableQuery` attribute.
However the second endpoint is registered as EDM entity in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(
        options =>
        {
            options.AddRouteComponents("api/odata", GetEdmModel());
            options.Select().SetMaxTop(1000).Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count();
            options.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
        }
    )
    .AddODataNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        cfg.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        cfg.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        cfg.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

The GetEdmModel function:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel() 
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    //var xxx = builder.EntitySet<[entityName]>("[ControllerName]");
    var wheaterForecast = builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast");
    builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Note the `NullValueHandling` in the `AddNewtonSoftJson` extension method call.

The response for the first endpoint does not include properties with null value:

```
[
    {
        "key": 0,
        "date": "2023-12-02T12:59:20.1791028Z",
        "temperatureC": -8,
        "temperatureF": 18,
        "summary": "Scorching"
    },
    {
        "key": 0,
        "date": "2023-12-03T12:59:20.1818921Z",
        "temperatureC": 39,
        "temperatureF": 102,
        "summary": "Scorching"
    },
    ... more data
]
```

The second endpoint however still includes these properties:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:7669/api/odata/$metadata#WeatherForecast",
    "value": [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "date": "2023-12-02T12:59:16.0874576Z",
            "temperatureC": -4,
            "summary": "Sweltering",
            "myProperty": null
        },
        {
            "key": 0,
            "date": "2023-12-03T12:59:16.2152018Z",
            "temperatureC": 47,
            "summary": "Mild",
            "myProperty": null
        },
        ... more data
    ]
}
```

I see the response model is different but would like the properties with null values also to be excluded.

Is that possible or is there any reason why it is still included.
I assume it uses a different serializer in that case.

Tried different settings on the Newtonsoft extension methods but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:
package`Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`
Create a OmitNullResourceSerializer.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.Serialization;
using Microsoft.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;

namespace WebApplication86
{
    public class OmitNullResourceSerializer : ODataResourceSerializer
    {
        public OmitNullResourceSerializer(IODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider) : base(serializerProvider)
        {
        }

        public override ODataProperty CreateStructuralProperty(IEdmStructuralProperty structuralProperty, ResourceContext resourceContext)
        {
                object propertyValue = resourceContext.GetPropertyValue(structuralProperty.Name);
                if (propertyValue == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }        
            return base.CreateStructuralProperty(structuralProperty, resourceContext);
        }
    }
}
```

EdmModelBuilder.cs

```
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;

namespace WebApplication86
{
    public class EdmModelBuilder
    {
        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast");
            builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

WeatherForecast.cs

```
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public string? myProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace WebApplication86.Controllers
{
    [Route("odata")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ODataController
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        [HttpGet("Weatherforecast")]
        [EnableQuery]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .AsQueryable();

            return Ok(query);
        }
    }
}
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
        options =>
        {
            options.AddRouteComponents("odata", EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel(),services => services.AddSingleton<ODataResourceSerializer, OmitNullResourceSerializer>()).EnableQueryFeatures();
            options.Select().SetMaxTop(1000).Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count();
            options.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
        }
    );
```

Test result
[image]

Be careful about the "using path".

Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/extension-omit-null-value-properties-in-asp-net-core-odata/